# GNU Make only uses 4 threads no matter what --jobs is

Tags: docker, makefile, gnu-make

Whatever `--jobs` argument I pass to make, I'm always getting 4 threads.

During `make --jobs=1 target` I can see on stdout lines that start with `make[1]:`, `make[2]:`, `make[3]:` and `make[4]:` when I would only expect a single thread.

Same outcome if i use `make --jobs=100 target`, I get 4 threads instead of 100.

I'm not sure if that is relevant, but I run make inside a docker container and docker has 7 of my localhost cores available to it.

```
>docker info
Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 7
```

and inside the Alpine Linux docker container

```
>make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-alpine-linux-musl

>grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
7
```

confirming that the container gets 7 cores.

Is there something I could run that would help me narrow down why make behaves that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's some confusion: the number after `make` is not a thread number.  Make is not actually multithreaded, it's single-threaded.

That number is the depth of recursive make processes which are being invoked.  It will always show up exactly the same (given the same targets) no matter how large (or small) your `-j` value, because it represents how many recursive instances of make have been invoked.

That is, if you have something like:

```
recurse:
        $(MAKE) ...
```

then messages from the top-level instance of make will be `make`, and messages from the sub-make invoked by the `recurse` recipe will be `make[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the meaning of the digit in `make[i]`, I didn't realize this was the depth in the recursion.

@MadScientist I'm not sure I understand your comment about Make being single-threaded. What do you think of https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html, how could Make run multiple jobs in parallel if it is a single-threaded application?

Comment: Because every job that make runs is a _separate process_.  Make doesn't have the code of a shell built into itself, it runs a separate shell program.  These programs all run in parallel (just like you can have a web browser and a terminal program running at the same time: this doesn't mean that your system is running these both in different threads of the same program).  When make wants to run things in parallel it runs multiple processes: it doesn't need to make a new thread for that.

Comment: Got it, make forks multiple processes for parallelism. Thanks.